# Website goes down after uploading Master page

Tags: asp.net, server, hosting, web-hosting

My question is about **Asp.Net website hosting on shared server**. I have a website which has **1 master page and 4000 child pages**, website is made in asp.net but pages are like static - I am ***not using any database*** in it. I simple create a child page from the master page, write the Title, Heading, Description & content. **Website has 30,000 to 40,000 pageviews per day**.
The issue is that: **When I make any change in the master page, website went down for 3-4 hours. No issue with child page uploading** - to upload the pages I use FileZilla(any number of child page can be uploaded and no Issue of website down).
I am using [GoDaddy's Ultimate Windows Hosting plan](https://in.godaddy.com/hosting/windows-hosting)
**Here is my Master page code:**

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="mpageR.master.vb" Inherits="mywebsite" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/W3.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css"/>

    <!-- START: Analytics-->
    <!-- Analytics code-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    ...
    </script>
    <!-- END: Analytics Code-->

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>

    <!--Main Page Section-->
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="w3-row">
            <!--Header control (reading a file in this control to show header section)-->
            <%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="header_cntrl"   Src="~/user-controls/header.ascx" %>
            <uc:header_cntrl id="header_cntrl1" runat="server"/>
            <!--End of Header-->
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row">
            <!--main section-->
                <div class="left-panel">
                    <!-- Left Nav Menu (reading file for left panel)-->
                    <%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="LeftNavMenu"   Src="~/plugins/LeftNavMenu.ascx" %>
                    <uc:LeftNavMenu id="LeftNavMenu" runat="server"/>
                    <!-- End of Left Nav Menu-->
                </div>
                <div class="main-panel">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">        
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
                <div class="right-panel">
                    <!-- Right Nav Menu (reading file for right section)-->
                    <%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="RgtNavMenu"   Src="~/plugins/RgtNavMenu.ascx" %>
                    <uc:RgtNavMenu id="RgtNavMenu" runat="server"/>
                    <!-- End of Right Nav Menu-->
                </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <!--Footer control (reading file for footer)-->
        <%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="footer_cntrl"   Src="~/user-controls/footer.ascx" %>
        <uc:footer_cntrl id="footer_master" runat="server"/>
        <!--End of Footer-->

    </form>
    <!--End of Main Page Section-->
</body>
</html>
```

**Web.config file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    </compilation>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>

    <customErrors mode="On">
      <error redirect="~/error.aspx" statusCode="404"/>
    </customErrors>

  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mywebsiye.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mywebsite.com/{R:0}"
                  redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You say it "goes down" but didn't provide any sort of detail. Specifically what is the error you're getting? What do the error logs say?

Comment: Sorry - website shows ERROR 403 forbidden and then after a few minutes shows server not reachable (under the cloudflare, which I am using for HTTPS) and then no msg just waiting waiting ... Traffic is also not come together, it comes very slowly like 5 live vistor and then 6 then 10 and then sudden 0. But after more than 3 hours, it started showing around 100 live visitors (which is our average live visitor at  any moment)

Comment: I told to the hosting company they told your master page is not optimized and sometimes they told use my name servers and remove cloudflare's name server. I have verified at that mement cloudflare works fine but server is not reachable.

Comment: One more thing, I want to add here - when child pages were less like less than 1000  same thing happened but the slow down time was 30-40 minutes.